# Rake parallel:prepare changes schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parallel-testing

I'm using parallel_tests on a Rails 3.2 app and we have two developers, everytime I do a 'rake parallel:prepare' I get this change and it's the opposite for the other programmer.

```
-    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
-    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
+    t.datetime "created_at"
+    t.datetime "updated_at"
```

I really want rails to keep those constraints on and not try and remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You or your colleague should reload schema (or all migrations) to database in development env.